# Compare sound between source and microphone in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, microphone, audio-fingerprinting

I'm working about audio but I'm a newbie in this area. I would like to **matching sound from microphone to my source audio(just only 1 sound)** like Coke Ads from Shazam. [Example Video](https://youtu.be/jdvteFAmG_k?t=46s) (0.45 minute) However, I want to make it on website by JavaScript. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building something similar to the backend of Shazam is not an easy task. We need to:

1. Acquire audio from the user's microphone (easy)
2. Compare it to the source and identify a match (hmm... how do... )

How can we perform each step?

## Aquire Audio

This one is a definite no biggy. We can use the `Web Audio API` for this. You can google around for good tutorials on how to use it. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Basic_concepts_behind_Web_Audio_API) provides some good fundametal knowledge that you may want to understand when using it.

## Compare Samples to Audio Source File

Clearly this piece is going to be an algorithmic challenge in a project like this. There are probably various ways to approach this part, and not enough time to describe them all here, but one feasible technique (which happens to be what Shazam actually uses), and which is also described in greater detail [here](https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/shazam-it-music-processing-fingerprinting-and-recognition), is to create and compare against a sort of fingerprint for smaller pieces of your source material, which you can generate using FFT analysis.

This works as follows:

1. Look at small sections of a sample no more than a few seconds long (note that this is done using a sliding window, not discrete partitioning) at a time
2. Calculate the Fourier Transform of the audio selection. This decomposes our selection into many signals of different frequencies. We can analyze the frequency domain of our sample to draw useful conclusions about what we are hearing.
3. Create a fingerprint for the selection by identifying critical values in the FFT, such as peak frequencies or magnitudes
4. If you want to be able to match multiple samples like Shazam does, you should maintain a dictionary of fingerprints, but since you only need to match one source material, you can just maintain them in a list. Since your keys are going to be an array of numerical values, I propose that another possible data structure to quickly query your dataset would be a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). I don't think Shazam uses one, but the more I think about it, the closer their system seems to an n-dimensional nearest neighbor search, if you can keep the amount of critical points consistent. For now though, just keep it simple, use a list.

Now we have a database of fingerprints primed and ready for use. We need to compare them against our microphone input now.

5. Sample our microphone input in small segments with a sliding window, the same way we did our sources.
6. For each segment, calculate the fingerprint, and see if it matches close to any from storage. You can look for a partial match here and there are lots of tweaks and optimizations you could try.
7. This is going to be a noisy and inaccurate signal so don't expect every segment to get a match. If lots of them are getting a match (you will have to figure out what lots means experimentally), then assume you have one. If there are relatively few matches, then figure you don't.

## Conclusions

This is not going to be an super easy project to do well. The amount of tuning and optimization required will prove to be a challenge. Some microphones are inaccurate, and most environments have other sounds, and all of that will mess with your results, but it's also probably not as bad as it sounds. I mean, this is a system that from the outside seems unapproachably complex, and we just broke it down into some relatively simple steps.

Also as a final note, you mention Javascript several times in your post, and you may notice that I mentioned it zero times up until now in my answer, and that's because language of implementation is not an important factor. This system is complex enough that the hardest pieces to the puzzle are going to be the ones you solve on paper, so you don't need to think in terms of "how can I do X in Y", just figure out an algorithm for X, and the Y should come naturally.